# Metadata related to RecordList Component in Experience Builder

Tags: community, force.com-sites, metadata, digital-experience, experience-bundle

Where can I track metadata related to Show list search header property of record list component. I unchecked the field and retrieved experience bundle in VS Code editor but still in recordList.json file I can see showSearchBar as true.

[image]

Where can I see correct metadata for this option ? and can we update it from VS Code Editor ?

[image]